# R-shiny show certain plot if conditions are met

Tags: user-interface, shiny, heatmap

In my server.R I have:

```
output$interactive <- renderIHeatmap(...

output$static <- renderPlot(...
```

Both of these render heatmaps, one interactive, one static.  Is there a way that shiny can automatically choose to display the static heatmap if the row or column dimensions of the heatmap is greater than a specific number?  So something like...

```
box(width = NULL, solidHeader = TRUE,
      if (heatmap_rows<100) {
         iHeatmapOutput('interactive')
      } else  {
         plotOutput('static')
      })
```

Thank you for your time. I apologize if this is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is conditionalPanel().

In server.R, you need to make an output variable that is the number of rows:

```
shinyServer(function(input,output,session){
  output$heatmap_rows <- renderText(nrow(heatmap_data))
}
```

In your ui.R, you need to display that output somewhere. You can probably hide it cleverly with .css, but it has to actually go into the html of your page, or else you won't be able to condition on it with conditionalPanel.

So here's the general idea in ui.R:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  mainPanel(

    #Note the output.heatmap_rows syntax. That's JavaScript.
    conditionalPanel("output.heatmap_rows < 100", 
                     iHeatmapOutput('interactive')
    ),
    conditionalPanel("output.heatmap_rows >= 100",
                     plotOutput('static')
    )
  ),

  #This has to be somewhere on the page, and it has to render.
  #Alter the css and make its' text the same color as the background.
  verbatimTextOutput("heatmap_rows")

))
```

I haven't found a better way to condition on data from the output. You could probably hide all of that logic behind a uiRender in server.R as well.